# Cannot change TimeMachine locking passphrase because of newline character

Tags: terminal, time-machine

I accenditally used a passphrase that contains a newline character for one of my TM volumes. So my passphrase contains e.g.

```
MYPASSPHRASE
```

Although it should be (without the trailing newline)

```
MYPASSPHRASE
```

My problem is that I need to copy/paste the passphrase from a text editor because typing it does not work (which is not convenient nor secure)

I already tried to change the password using DiskUtility (File menu > Change password...) or using the terminal with this:

```
pss=$(echo -e -n 'MYPASSPHRASE\n')
diskutil cs passwd 12345678-ABCD-FEDC-7654-ABCDEF1234 -oldpassphrase $pss -newpassphrase MYNEWPASSPHRASE
```

I also tried the `-stdinpassphrase` option but with no luck in any case:

```
Error: -69725: Unable to change the Core Storage passphrase
```

Does someone has a lead on how to change this "corrupted" passphrase or do I need to copy the content of my backup to a new volume as a last chance option ?